# Weak Compositions with Size Restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a number of elements and I'm trying to place them into boxes but one of the boxes has a restriction on the number of elements that can be placed into it, how do you account for that in the weak composition formula?

Example:

Say I were trying to put 30 balls into 6 boxes but the first box must have less than 6 balls in it. Is there any way to find the number of compositions other than summing the compositions of when the first box has zero to five balls (which is what I'm currently attempting to do)?

Thanks!

Comment: Not convinced that there is a nice formula. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/299958/586 .

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by subtracting the number of invalid compositions (e.g. with 6 or more balls in the first box) from the number of unrestricted compositions. Both can be expressed as binomial coefficients by using "stars and bars".