# Distribute indistinguishable objects to containers with different sizes

Tags: combinatorics

I want to distribute *n* indistinguishable objects to *k* containers with *s0,s1,...,sk* sizes. The order of the objects and the distrubution in one container doens't matter, only their amount counts. I tried several things with binomial and multinomial coefficients, be were unable to solve the problem. Any help or ideas are appreciated.

Here an example to clarify: You have 7 objects and 2 containers with sizes of 5 and 3. It is possible to put 5 objects in the first and 2 objects in the second container. It is also possible to put 4 objects in the first and 3 objects in the second container. So the possible distributions are 2.

Comment: "...with sizes of 3 and 5. It is possible to put 5 objects in the first..." Shouldn't that be "in the second"?

Comment: @leonbloy you are right, I changed the numbers

Comment: Related (almost dup) : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363619/weak-compositions-with-size-restrictions

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21645/restricted-compositions

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_i\leq si$ , $i=0,1,2,\dots,k$ and $\sum_im_i=n $. Choose $m_0$ objects from $n$ objects and put them in the container $s_0$ which of size $s0$, and choose $m_1$ objects from $n-m_0$ objects and put them in the container $s_1$,..., and choose $m_k$ objects from $n-m_0-m_1-\ldots -m_{k-1}$ objects and put them in the container $s_k$. This mean is

$C(n,m_0). C(n-m_0,m_1)\ldots C(n-m_0-m_1-\ldots -m_{k-1},m_k)=\frac{n!}{m_0!.m_1!.\ldots m_k!}$

So the answer is $\sum_{m_i\leq si,\sum_im_i=n }\frac{n!}{m_0!.m_1!.\ldots m_k!}$