# The maximum amount of n-tuples which are not superior to one another

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a combinatoric question, which might be classical but I can't find any references to it.

We define a 'n-tuple' to be a element in $\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\}^n$, where $m\in\mathbb{N}_+$. We say one n-tuple $X=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ is superior to another $Y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ if and only if
$$x_i\geq y_i,\forall i=1,2,\ldots,n$$
Now I want to know at most how many distinct n-tuples could be chosen, so that any one of them cannot be superior to one another?

All what I know is in the situation $m=2$ this is precisely Sperner Family, and I guess this question, as a generalization, is tough. So thank you in advance, even for some further information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a special case of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299770/12042). In your case the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299958/12042) given there reduces to $$|A_r|=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{r+n-1-km}{n-1}\;,$$ where $$r=\left\lfloor\frac12(n-1)m\right\rfloor\;.$$ $A_r$ is the antichain consisting of all $n$-tuples whose components sum to $r$.