# Probability no more than 7 from 300 randomly chosen people have birthday on the same week

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find a probability that from $300$ randomly chosen people no more than $7$ have birthday on this week (not day of week).

I'm trying to solve it asymptotatically in Bernoulli scheme.

$ P_n^m = \frac{(np)^m}{m!} e^{-np} $, where $ n = 300, m = 7 $.

I assume that probabilty $ p $ is the chance being born on a random week during the year: $ p = 7/365 $. But I'm not sure that's correct, because week should be the same for all $ 7 $ men.

Comment: At some point you'll need Inclusion-Exclusion (or something like that).  It's easy to get the probability that at least $8$ of them were born in some given week, but then you can't just multiply by $52$ (or whatever you had in mind) because that would multiply count scenarios in which two or more weeks saw at least $8$ births.  I suggest sampling first.

Comment: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475169/maximum-number-of-balls-thrown-into-k-urns-with-equal-probability) is a quasi-duplicate (without a satisfactory analytic solution).

Comment: Note:  the fact that $300$ is only slightly less than $52\times 6$ might make it possible to enumerate all the "good" distributions.  Tedious, but maybe not all that hard.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you mean, specifically, "There is no single week that has 8 people born in it"?

Comment: @arthur we don't think about other weeks, just about this particular week which should have no more than 7 birthdays (can be on the same day).

Comment: @lulu: But the good distributions include those with seven birthdays in some weeks, right? So we've got to include all the different combinations from $7^{42}\times6\times0^{9}$ over to $6^{40}\times5^{12}$. That sounds more than merely tedious, barring computer aid. I think an approximation seems likely the way to go.

Comment: @BrianTung  Yeah, I assumed computer assistance.  And, sure, estimation is almost certainly better.  Though it appears that the OP was only interested in one fixed week.  Seems unlikely....

Comment: If you only care about one week in particular, this is a routine binomial problem.  But is that actually what you meant?  I don't think anyone would interpret your post that way.

Comment: @lulu yes, it's definitely a binomial problem. I was trying to use Pouisson for it and I'm not sure that I assume probabilty correctly.

Comment: @lulu The "good" distributions, if I'm not mistaken, are  53417 (way more than I'd expected) https://jsfiddle.net/4xbdmo2u/2/

Comment: @leonbloy  Yeah...even with a computer, that's a dumb way to go.  But it seems that the OP meant a different question anyway.

Comment: MathWonk's solution to the problem we initially thought it was, was rather clever. I'm chagrined not to have thought of it, because usually I do come up with a generating function approach. But I was going to say that the approximation @leonbloy came up with would dramatically overestimate the probability of a "good" outcome, since the measure is over a $52$-simplex, which has a ton of space out in the corners, while the approximation makes it much closer to a "fuzzy" $52$-sphere. But it's all irrelevant since it's not the question intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we round at 52 weeks, the problem is equivalent to: throw $B=300$ balls into $U=52$ urns, uniformly; find the probability that all urns have at most $M=7$ balls.

This correspond to counting weak compositions with restrictions, which is difficult to solve exactly (see [eg](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299958/312)).

An approximation (Poissonization) consist of assuming that the original (multinomial) model is approximated by $M$ iid Poisson variables of mean $\lambda = B/U$. Then the probability we want is

$$P\approx \left( \sum_{k=0}^M e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \right)^U$$

This gives a very small probability ($\approx 1.76 \cdot 10^{-6}$)

Update: The question was edited, and now has a very different meaning (at most 7 birthday on *this* week), so this answer does not apply.