# Combinatorics with fixed repetition

Tags: combinatorics

I don't have the required skills to solve this problem. I would appreciate it, if anyone could help me: 
You have k boxes, N balls and every box can contain a maximum of t balls, where t is for every box different. The boxes are distinguishable, the balls not. It is also possible that a box contains nothing. How many different solutions are possible?
I can compute all solutions, but the condition is missing. Is it possible to subtract all wrong solutions?

Comment: Are the balls distinguishable?

Answer (score 2):

So far as I know, there is no closed form solution for this general problem.

Let me change the notation: you have $n$ balls, $m$ boxes, and box $k$ (for $k=1,\ldots,m$) has a maximum capacity of $t_k$. Let $[m]^k$ denote the family of subsets of $[m]=\{1,\ldots,m\}$ of cardinality $k$. Then a combination of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) and the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) allow one to deduce that there are

$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\sum_{S\in[m]^k}\binom{n+m-1-\sum\limits_{i\in S}(t_i+1)}{m-1}=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\sum_{S\subseteq[m]^k}\binom{n+m-k-1-\sum\limits_{i\in S}t_i}{m-1}$$

solutions. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265420/12042) to essentially the same problem with very different notation I gave more of the details of the reasoning; [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203839/12042) gives full details for a simpler problem with specific numbers.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded) Marc van Leeuwen deals with exactly your problem, starting with the simpler case in which all of the limits $t_k$ are equal using an approach via generating functions.

Comment: @BrianMScott: Thanks for providing an answer with references to  a lot of related problems. (+1)