# Number of ordered triples, given upper bounds?

Tags: combinatorics

So I know that I can solve a questions like "$x+y+z = 100$, how many triples can you make?" using stars and bars. However, how do I attempt to solve these when there are upper bounds on the values of $x$, $y$, or $z$. For instance, say this is the question:

$$x+y+z = 5 \\ x\leq4,\ y\leq5,\ z\leq3$$

How many ordered triples can I make?

Comment: Have you used generating functions before?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Then it's the coefficient of $x^5$ in $$(1+x+\cdots+x^4)(1+x+\cdots+x^5)(1+x+\cdots+x^3)$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Principle of Exclusion and Inclusion?

Comment: A small problem like this is also easily solved with an inclusion-exclusion argument: start with the unrestricted solutions and subtract the ones that violate the upper bounds.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673834/determine-how-many-integer-solutions-to-the-inequality-x-1x-2-x-5-lt-110/3674138#3674138 is a more complicated example, that is most easily done with generating functions.

Comment: @StashuKozlowski or Brian. Could you please explain how to easily do this with Principle of Exclusion/Inclusion? I know the principle, it just seems like there are a lot of cases?

Comment: @James: There can be a lot of cases, but there aren’t always. For instance, in the example in your question the constraint on $y$ can be ignored, since no solution can violate it, and it’s also impossible for a solution to violate **both** of the other two constraints, so it’s really just a matter of three calculations: $\binom72$ unrestricted solutions, $1$ solution violating the constraint on $x$, and $\binom32$ solutions violating the constraint on $z$, i.e., essentially the non-negative solutions to $x+y+z=1$.

Comment: @james: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522078/inclusion-exclusion/522100#522100) is a slightly less trivial example, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265410/how-many-combination-can-we-create-from-this-structure/265420#265420) is a general result embedded in the solution to another problem.

Comment: See [balls in bins with limited capacity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm)